# Avoid user change without public key

Tags: raspbian, permissions, user

I set public key authentication on my rpi and disabled password login in the *sshd_config* file. There are two users: `userA` and `userB`, while `userA` is my main user. In addition there are two computers (`pc1` and `pc2`).

I created diffrent keys for both computers as usual. `pc1` should be able to log in to both users. So I added his public key to both user's *authorized_keys* file.

`pc2` shall not be able to log in to `userA`. That's why I added his public key only to `userB`'s *authorized_keys* file.

Now if I try to log in from `pc2` with `$ ssh userA@hostname` the permission is denied like I wanted, while log in to `userB` is allowed. Everything works greate so far.

**But** when I log in from `pc2` to `userB` an run `$ su userA` I'm still able to access `userA` by just enter the password.

Is there a possibility to avoid this? I don't want `pc2` to be able to log in on `userA` at all.

Comment: You could limit the execution permissions on `su` to a particular group and exclude `userB`, if it is okay that `userB` be completely unable to use `su`.

Comment: Sounds perfect, how do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a couple of ways you could prevent `userB` from using `su` period; the first one is via a mechanism provided by [PAM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pluggable_authentication_module); it may differ slightly from distro to distro but the description on current versions of Raspbian from `/etc/pam.d/su` is:

```
# Uncomment this to force users to be a member of group root
# before they can use `su'. You can also add "group=foo"
# to the end of this line if you want to use a group other
# than the default "root" (but this may have side effect of
# denying "root" user, unless she's a member of "foo" or explicitly
# permitted earlier by e.g. "sufficient pam_rootok.so").
# (Replaces the `SU_WHEEL_ONLY' option from login.defs)
# auth       required   pam_wheel.so
```

Since `sufficient pam_rootok.so` is probably already enabled (immediately above this part), if you would like to create a group and use that rather than putting other users who should have `su` access into group `root`, first create a new group:

```
sudo groupadd usesu
```

Then uncomment that line and edit a bit:

```
auth       required   pam_wheel.so group=usesu
```

I presume this should take effect right away.  To add a user to the group, see the `-a` and `-G` options to `man usermod`; note that once added to a group you have to re-login for that to take effect.

If that doesn't seem to work, you can change the ownership and permissions on `su` directly:

```
sudo chgrp usesu $(which su)
sudo chmod 4750 $(which su)
```

The 4 at the beginning is for the [setuid bit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid) necessary to `su`'s functioning, the 750 means read-write-execute for owner (root) and read-execute for group (usesu), nothing for anyone else.

Comment: The first way worked perfectly. I just added `group=sudo`, for only sudoers can use `su`. Thank you!